# Error after installing Rcmdr package

Tags: r

I got the error below. Any idea how to fix this?

> library (Rcmdr)
>   Loading required package: splines
>   Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
>   Loading required package: car
>   Loading required package: sandwich
>   Rcmdr Version 2.1-7
>   Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘Rcmdr’ was built under R version 3.2.1
>   2: package ‘RcmdrMisc’ was built under R version 3.2.1
>   3: package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.2.1
>   4: package ‘sandwich’ was built under R version 3.2.1
>   Error in (function ()  : 
>     4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3

Comment: Try `suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(Rcmdr)))`

Answer (score 0):

I installed the library now and it asked me to install many others but it worked when I did allow it.
Did you install all the others as well?